# What is the correct way to use feign with spring cloud kubernetes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Spring Cloud Kubernetes and I am trying to make feign able to send requests based on the name of the services present in kubernetes, but I can't, when I try to make a request the following error occurs:

```
  "timestamp": "2019-12-06T15:37:50.285+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: poc-saldo",
    "trace": "java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: poc-saldo\n\tat org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute....
```

I tried to call other services within the cluster and the problem is the same for all of them, I did a test by going into the poc-deposit pod and doing a poc-balance curl and it works normally, so the problem is not with the poc-deposit service. balance or with kubernetes's service discovery apparently.

The project has a public profile at:

```
https://gitlab.com/viniciusxyz/spring-kubernetes-feign
```

For those who want more direct information:

My main class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class ServiceDiscoveryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceDiscoveryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My interface with feign is as follows:

```
@FeignClient("poc-saldo")
public interface ProxyGenerico {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String getHttpResponse();

}
```

I can list the services available in kubernetes within the application as follows:

```
@RestController
public class RestTest {

    @Autowired
    private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    @Autowired
    private ProxyGenerico proxyGenerico;

    @GetMapping("/services")
    public ResponseEntity<?> services()  {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(discoveryClient.getServices(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/pocsaldo")
    public ResponseEntity<?> gitlab()  {

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(proxyGenerico.getHttpResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

And in this list I have several services among them the service I want to access called poc-balance, the return json looks like the following:

```
[

    "poc-deposito",
    "poc-saldo",
    "sonarqube",
    "sql-server-sonar",
    "zookeeper",
    "gitlab"

]
```

To complement the list follow my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The discoveryClient.getInstances ("poc-saldo") command returns:

```
[
    {
        "instanceId": "32a4db0d-0549-11ea-8850-e0d55ef66cf8",
        "serviceId": "poc-saldo",
        "secure": false,
        "metadata": {
            "helm.sh/chart": "spring-boot-app-0.1.23",
            "port.http": "8080",
            "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "Tiller",
            "app.kubernetes.io/name": "poc-saldo",
            "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "banco-digital-poc-saldo",
            "app.kubernetes.io/version": "1.0"
        },
        "port": 8080,
        "host": "10.42.0.60",
        "scheme": "http://",
        "uri": "http://10.42.0.60:8080"
    }
]
```

Can you think of where the problem might be?

Comment: Are you using `eureka` as your service discovery? If not, how would it know where those services are. In such case, you should configure their urls as `<app>.ribbon.listOfServers=http://<app-host>/...`

Comment: I am using Spring Cloud Kubernetes which uses Kubernetes service discovery, eureka is just one of the supported service discovery providers.

Comment: In your case, can you see those services listed in kubernetes?

Comment: Yes, as I described, I can see the list of services in my kubernete by injecting the object that implements DiscoveryClient.

Comment: Okay. since you are looking at services, may be it's better to make `getInstances` call for those services and see what their `instance-id` looks like. That is the id that needs to match the names you have shown

Comment: I couldn't understand your idea, can you explain a little more?

Comment: I was saying can you check getInstances() call response and see if you find any anomalies in values.

Comment: I added the command return, but to me it seems all normal.

Comment: Okay. The next step I would check is the health. can you run a health check and see if it reports them UP or DOWN?

Comment: Have you enable Ribbon in properties? I mean ribbon.http.client.enabled=true

Comment: The applications are UP, watching the ip being returned is the internal ip of kubernetes, I tried to set spring.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.mode to service, but the default of the internal ip of kubernetes remains

Comment: The ribbon is already active by default, but I added the property anyway, but from what I understand of the ribbon it gets the ips and does the load balance on the client side and if it is receiving the kubernetes ip will not work anyway since the cluster is not on my machine.

Comment: They might be getting filtered. put a breakpoint in `public List<Server> getEligibleServers(List<Server> servers, Object loadBalancerKey) {` method of `AbstractServerPredicate` class

Comment: This looks like a similar issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/197#issuecomment-401143476

Comment: Unfortunately I already saw this issue and tried to use the spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all dependency, but when I do that I get an error saying that I don't have a discovery service available and then I have to add the spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes- dependency. ribbon to at least get the service up

Comment: Hello @ViniciusVieira did You manage to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes and no, I ended up giving up using spring cloud kubernetes because using kubernetes' own services turned out to be much more efficient and straightforward than using libraries, I will post an answer in this article today as soon as I leave work.

Comment: To summarize, I use the feign as a parameter for the url of the kubernetes service, something like: @FeignClient ("http: // kubernetes-service"), I'm giving this example just in case you have the same problem and need a quick solution, the night post a complete answer.

Comment: @ViniciusVieira Ok so there is no way of using FeignClient same way as in Eureka. What I found out is that instead of @FeignClient("service-name") You can do @FeignClient(url="service-name") and it works without passing full address `http://service-name:port`

Comment: You've helped me a lot @ViniciusVieira! Thank you so much! Maybe you should answer this topic with the HTTP solution you've posted above. That's how I sorted it out too.

Comment: There is still no opportunity to test without adding the "http", next week you will start migrating and get a test, as it is a more user-friendly way to reply or post after purchasing a feature from it.

Comment: As I read from a book "An advantage of using Kubernetes discovery service is that it doesn't require a client library such as Netflix Ribbon, which we have been using together with Netflix Eureka. ". Hope that help you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Long story short, **Spring Cloud Feign works perfectly fine with Spring Cloud Kubernetes** as of July 2021. I've moved a *Spring Cloud Feign* project from using *Spring Cloud Netflix* to *Spring Cloud Kubernetes* and no change in the Feign interfaces was required. I just removed the previous *Service Registry (Eureka)* dependency from my `build.gradle` file and added:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all'
```

The support for *Spring Cloud LoadBalancer* which is now used by *Spring Cloud Feign* was added to *Spring Cloud Kubernetes* and *Ribbon* was removed as of **Spring Cloud 2020.0. (aka Ilford)**, therefore there is no need to exclude it anymore.

Beyond that, the only change required in the whole codebase was annotating the Spring Boot application class with `@EnableDiscoveryClient` to enable K8s-native Service Discovery:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookApplication {
```

*Spring Cloud Feign* uses *Spring Cloud LoadBalancer* which when running on Kubernetes leverages [Discovery Client for Kubernetes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#discoveryclient-for-kubernetes) to check for service instances. As a result, it only chooses from instances that are up and running. **The only requirement is to align the Kubernetes service name with**  `spring.application.name` **property**. Just like that:

*application.properties(yaml)*:

```
spring.application.name=library-book-service
```

combined with the following Kubernetes configuration

*kubectl get svc*:

```
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
library-book-service       ClusterIP   10.100.200.235   <none>        8080/TCP            5d21h
```

Answer (score 0):

If you  use Ribbon for load balancing  I see it  in your  error `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient`

You need  say  Ribbon about real address all your  microservices and
use for this action discovery Client.

1. Above your main class, add a few annotation

   ```
   @EnableDiscoveryClient
   @AutoConfigureAfter(RibbonAutoConfiguration.class)
   @RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration = RibbonConfiguration.class) 
   public class MyApp
   ```
2. Add implementations yours dynamic Server List

   ```
   public class MyServerList extends AbstractServerList<Server> {
       private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
       private IClientConfig clientConfig;

       public MyServerList(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
           this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
       }

       @Override
       public List<Server> getInitialListOfServers() {
           return getUpdatedListOfServers();
       }

       @Override
       public List<Server> getUpdatedListOfServers() {
           Server[] servers = discoveryClient.getInstances(clientConfig.getClientName()).stream()
               .map(i -> new Server(i.getHost(), i.getPort()))
               .toArray(Server[]::new);
           return Arrays.asList(servers);
       }

       @Override
       public void initWithNiwsConfig(IClientConfig clientConfig) {
           this.clientConfig = clientConfig;
       } 
   }
   ```
3. Add RibbonConfiguration.class

   ```
   public class RibbonConfiguration {

       @Autowired
       private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

       @Bean
       @ConditionalOnMissingBean
       public ServerList<?> ribbonServerList(IClientConfig config) {
           MyServerList myserverLis = new MyServerList(discoveryClient);
           myserverLis.initWithNiwsConfig(config);
           return myserverLis;
       }
   }
   ```

and you can config in your app property  refresh  time  I  mean period  of  time call getUpdatedListOfServers